# Encoding problems in SharePoint2007 recycle bin

Tags: 2007, encoding, recycle-bin

I am having problems with the Encoding in SharePoint recycle bin.I have create an item with title "abcabc",after deletion I went to the recycle bin , I got "弓ᱜ同䢴᪜ޛ翍⺉"as title in recycle bin.I think it is the problem with encoding.

Does someone else have the same problem?